question about fraction axioms,proofs of properties of fractions
I want to ask a question as a university student) I really love strict and complete mathematics. I don’t like to learn and cram something and I want to understand and axiomize.  I want to ask a question: why, when multiplying and dividing the numerator and denominator of a fraction, the fraction itself does not change its value.  and what does it mean to reduce, why can we reduce the numerator and denominator of a fraction?  why can we multiply fractions, how are they multiplied, for example, why can we multiply 10 by 1/2 and what kind of number will it be?  Of course, I understand everything perfectly and intuitively, and I’ve read a couple of books about number theory, but somehow I still want to figure it out and prove all these facts as strictly as possible, intuitively and clearly they are very clear to me

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
